# Functions & Points

Tags: functions

Suppose there are three functions *f(x), g(x)* & *h(x)* and there is a *point A*. Is there any method by which I may know that how many of the given functions pass via point A, and which are those functions ?

Comment: By the way, f(x), g(x) & h(x) are sine functions...

Comment: Calculate the values for $x$ the first coordinate of $A$.

Comment: You mean $f,g,h$ are *sinusoidal* functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any sine curve can be written as a  vertically shifted [sinusoidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) function, $f(t) = B\sin(\omega t+\phi) + C,\ $ where $B, C, \omega$ and $\phi$ are real constants.

The [amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude) of $f(t)$ is $B$ because the function $\sin$ takes all values between $-1$ and $1$. Therefore the range of the $f(t)$ is $[C-B,C+B]$.

So if the y-coordinate of $A \in [C-B,C+B],$ then $f(t)$ passes through $A$. Else it doesn't.

Comment: by " A belongs to [C-B, C+B] "; did you mean y coordinate of A ?

Comment: yes. I’ll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a function $f(x)=x^3$ and consider two points $P_1=(2,4) and P_2=(-2,-4$. Now, check if the function $f$ passing through the points $P_1$ and $P_2$. For $P_1$,
$f(2)=4$ so f passes through the point $P_1$. For $P_2$, $f(-2)=4=\neq -4$ so $f$ does not pass through the point $P_2$. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A=(x_0,y_0).$ To find out which functions pass through the point, if any, simply calculate $f(x_0),$ $g(x_0),$ and $h(x_0)$ to see if they are equal to $y_0.$